# How can i use many to one sql query with Java Spring?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, many-to-one

I am trying to make a search bar .This search bar must find animals with own name or owner name. Animal table have user_id as foreign key . I have to find animals with their owner name for that i think joining users table to animals .I use MySQL.

AnimalRepository.java

```
public interface AnimalRepository extends JpaRepository<Animal,Integer > {
    public Long countById(Integer id);
    
    @Query(value = "select * from animal join users  where name like %:keyword% or where users.name like %:keyword%", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Animal> findByKeyword(@Param("keyword") String keyword);

}
```

SearchPageController.java

```
    @Autowired
    private AnimalService animalService;

    @RequestMapping(path = {"/","/search"})
    public String home(Animal shop, Model model, String keyword) {
        if(keyword!=null) {
            List<Animal> list = animalService.getByKeyword(keyword);
            model.addAttribute("list", list);
        }else {
            List<Animal> list = animalService.getAllAnimals();
            model.addAttribute("list", list);}
        return "index";
    }
```

AnimalService.java

```
    public List<Animal> getAllAnimals(){
        List<Animal> list =  (List<Animal>)repo.findAll();
        return list;
    }

    public List<Animal> getByKeyword(String keyword){
        return repo.findByKeyword(keyword);
    }
```

[animal table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZisG.png)
[users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziQXv.png)

All code here: **https://github.com/Furkan-Ahmet-Ozdemir/Spring-vet**

** SOLVED: "select a.* from animals a inner join users u on u.id=a.user_id where a.name like %:keyword% or u.first_name like %:keyword%" **

Comment: I can find animals with their names and i want to find them with their owner name to.

Comment: try ilike %:keyword%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this one

```
@Query(value = "select a.* from animal a inner join users u on u.id=a.user_id where a.name like %:keyword% or u.name like %:keyword%", nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: I looked your query and edited . This one is working . "select a.* from animals a inner join users u on u.id=a.user_id where a.name like %:keyword% or u.first_name like %:keyword%"

Comment: @Furkan Happy for you and good luck!